# When to use a flat file over RDMS/NOSQL/etc

Tags: database, caching, nosql, scalability, flat-file

The domain of problems I work on are web applications and web APIs.

The longer I've been a developer, the more I've begun to question the need for a relational database even though the predominant thinking seems to be to stuff everything into a database.

When does it make sense to simply use a flat file for web applications and/or web APIs?

For example, it's my understanding that the massively scaled IRC which is decades old just appends chat conversations to an open flat file (no database, no caching, etc).

Does using flat files make you lose functionality, performance, data consistency, durability, etc ... especially given that database simple store information in flat files themselves?

Answer (score 1):

You have to work out your requirements. For example:

- Do you want transactions? If yes then a flat file is not good (BTW
  RDBMS files are NOT 'simple' flat files!)

  - Would a Key/Value db work? If yes, then maybe a NoSQL db would fit.
  - Resilience?
  - Replication?
  - Multiple complex data types? *Maybe* RDBMS.
    Work out all these (and probably more) and then see what fits...

Comment: What I'm looking for is someone to say Flat-files does x,y,z good, don't do a,b,c well. And then write the same good/bad use cases for RDMS, Key/Value, etc.

Comment: You sound like you've been developing for a while so you should be able to work it out yourself :) This link http://www.bing.com/search?setmkt=en-GB&q=how+to+decide+storage+type+dbms+NoSql+flat+file brought up this page http://www.databasedev.co.uk/flatfile-vs-rdbms.html - I'm sure that there are others. There isn't a short answer; it depends on a large number of requirements which will change with every implementation....

Answer (score 0):

You should go for a flat-file if you only need to create a file from content. (Like Blogs for example)

You will make a system that builds a to-be-used html, to serve it as a static asset after generating. It's way faster to handle code for this than to use a RDBMS.

If you need highly dynamic content, you should go for RDBMS because of performance, but you save A MILLION TRILLION BYTES OF RAM if you can go the route of generating static content and only some API endpoints. MySQL/MariaDB and MongoDB are Memory hogs as of today.

I really really tried to make Mongo and MySQL work on my 1GB RAM Server and it did always crash, meanwhile, my static page runs smoothly, and no ram is being used except for the socket of the HTTP Connection.

Most pages never really need dynamic content try to go for this if you want to give the user a smooth experience! Static Content all the way.